# Непроверяемые (Unchecked) исключения в Java

Tags: java, исключения

Какие непроверяемые исключения чаще всего встречаются в реальных проектах? (если можно отсортировать по частоте случаемости)

Comment: Погрепайте по сорс-хостингам например.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наиболее частые:

1. NullPointer
2. NumberFormat
3. IllegalArgument
4. IllegalState
5. NoSuchMethod
6. ClassCast

Данные приведены [отсюда](https://blog.takipi.com/the-top-10-exceptions-types-in-production-java-applications-based-on-1b-events/).

От себя хочу добавить, что ещё довольно часто встречается IndexOutOfRange (в университете нам говорили, что это топ 2 ошибок после nullPointer).

Англоязычные коллеги приводят аналогичную статистику [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502860/what-are-the-most-commonly-used-runtime-exceptions-in-java)